# SQLite analyze command slow after reboot

Tags: database, sqlite

**Summary:** Whenever I reboot my PC, the query ANALYZE on my SQLite DB takes about 3 minutes to perform even though I just did it right before rebooting.

Do I have to run another query to commit the statistics gathered during analyze?

**Long description:** I have a .NET application that takes readings from several sensors and adds the entry to a SQLite database.

The application starts when the PC boots up. The application will first have the database execute the query ANALYZE before adding rows.

The problem is that ANALYSE always takes a long time (~3min) but only after a reboot. If I close the application and open it again ANALYZE is performed in less than a second.

I have tried rebooting, manually performing ANALYZE with sqlite3.exe (took about 3 minutes again), rebooting again and performing ANALYZE again takes another 3 minutes.

The database consists of 4 tables with less than 500 rows, and 1 table with 1250000 rows.

Comment: Probably caching.

Comment: I would assume this is due to caching, but have tried enabling statistics? When was the last time you ran `vacuum`? That would probably help.